# ListView items reusing with paddings

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which contains items with different states. In one of these states item has `TextView` with custom background with paddings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid 
        android:color="@color/..." />
    <padding
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp" />
    <corners 
        android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

For all other states background is `null`.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result = convertView != null
                ? convertView
                : getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        final View statusView = result.findViewById(R.id.status);
        if (position % 4 == 0) {
            statusView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.target);
        } else {
            statusView.setBackground(null);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I scroll this list, some items without background have paddings after reusing.[image: screenshot]

The only solution I find to fix it is to reset paddings and background in adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result = convertView != null
                ? convertView
                : getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        final View statusView = result.findViewById(R.id.status);
        statusView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (position % 4 == 0) {
            statusView.setBackground(null);
            statusView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.target);
        } else {
            statusView.setBackground(null);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

but it's looks like a hack.

Has anybody faced the same problem? Or maybe knows how to fix it without hacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it it not a hack, according to [View.setBackground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29), you need to reset the padding explicitly.

> set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background. If
>   the background has padding, this View's padding is set to the
>   background's padding. However, **when a background is removed, this
>   View's padding isn't touched**. If setting the padding is desired,
>   **please use setPadding(int, int, int, int)**

If I understand correctly the code, even setting a new background without padding does not  change the current view's padding

Answer (score 0):

If you use two or more type of rows, you have to duplicate all custom elements, and set it for every row. So basically you need 2 for every row, drawables, text, `PADDING` etc.. or adapter will recycle some items, and sometimes not.

Example, here i change the icon on every row

```
    if (sqLite.imageReport(list.get(arg0).getId(), id_shop) == null) {
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
                R.drawable.ic_add_circle_green_36dp));
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
                R.drawable.ic_check_circle_blue_36dp));
    }
```